# eosio-cpp: command not found

Tags: smart-contract, eosiocpp

Is there an alias or PATH that we need to set for `eosio-cpp` to be accessible?

Here's what I'm seeing:

`~/eos/contracts/youvote $ eosio-cpp --help
eosio-cpp: command not found`

I can access it via:

`~/eos/contracts/youvote $ sudo /usr/local/eosio.cdt/bin/eosio-cpp --help
[sudo] password for user: 
OVERVIEW: eosio-cpp (Eosio C++ -> WebAssembly compiler)
USAGE: eosio-cpp [options] <input file> ...`

But, it's dangerous to run sudo for this script. Should the executable eosio-cpp be placed in a different folder or called some other way without sudo?

Thanks -Gunnar

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 2):

I needed to add read write permission to the eosio-cpp folder for non-sudo access.

`$ sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/eosio.cdt/bin/eosio-cpp`

and that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/v1.3.0/docs/installing-the-contract-development-toolkit#section-step-2-install) link, in order to make tools accessible anywhere, you have to run:

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

Comment: Thanks, kolkhi. I found out that I had to add read and execute permissions to the eosio-cpp folder using `$ sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/eosio.cdt/bin/eosio-cpp'

Comment: updated doc link https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs